# IntelliJ Rider global.json .NET Core

Tags: .net, json, macos, asp.net-core, rider

I have downloaded IntelliJ Rider for Mac OS.
How does one open solution with global.json file?
This is my project structure:

```
    ..
    src/
    test/
    global.json
```

This is global.json content:

```
 {
    "projects":[
      "src",
      "test"
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JetBrain's Rider does not support opening .NET Core applications unless they have an `.sln` and an `.xproj` file.

Here is a quote [from their recent release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/07/07/rider-eap-update-unit-testing-net-core-and-more/) that explains in more detail (emphasis added):

> Like Visual Studio, **Rider requires existing projects to have both  .sln and  .xproj files; it doesn’t support opening a  project.json file directly. And of course, with the recent announcements that  project.json is being replaced by MSBuild  .csproj files, it is now very unlikely that we will implement this support only for it be obsolete in a few months time.** If you have an existing project that only has  project.json, you can create a new project in a temporary folder and copy the  .sln and  .xproj files across and Rider will be able to open the project.